# PHP - Ajax Call - <b>Fatal error</b>: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

My website is currently in French, English and Dutch. French is the main language and the only one working up to now.

My jquery script makes an ajax call to a php page.

The response I got is this one : **Fatal error**:  Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in

How can I get rid of this error ? On the french version it works perfectly ! The 3 languages uses the same php script.

```
fermetureEtablissement = [] ;

$.ajax({
    type: "POST", 
    url: "./admin/datesajax.php", 
    data: ({idproduit: 'tous'}), 
    cache: false, 
    dataType: "json", 
    async: false, 
    success: function(data) {
        fermetureEtablissement = data;
    }
});
```

Do you have any idea how to fix this problem ?

You can see the not working page here :

1. Click on "book" on this page : http://www.velo-montagne.com/en/hotel/au-colombier-de-luxe-room
2. Then check the ajax call and the response. It shows the error.

You can see the working page here :

1. Click on "reserver" on this page : http://www.velo-montagne.com/hotel/chambre-au-colombier-de-luxe
2. Then check the ajax call and the response. It works great !

Example of dateajax.php :

```
if ($_POST['idproduit'] == 1 or $_POST['idproduit'] == 4 or $_POST['idproduit'] == 5 or $_POST['idproduit'] == 'tous' or $_POST['idproduit'] == 'ouverturesexceptionnelles' ){  
    $sth1 = $dbh->prepare("SELECT datesbloquees FROM vm_datesbloquees WHERE idproduit = :idproduit" );
    $sth1->execute(array(':idproduit' => $_POST['idproduit'])); 
    $result = $sth1->fetchAll();

    $tableaudatesbloquees = explode(",", $result[0]['datesbloquees']);
    //print_r($tableaudatesbloquees);
}


function dbConnect(){
  global $dbh;

  $dbInfo['database_target'] = "xxx";
  $dbInfo['database_name'] = "xxx";
  $dbInfo['username'] = "xxx";
  $dbInfo['password'] = "xxx";

  $dbConnString = "mysql:host=" . $dbInfo['database_target'] . "; dbname=" . $dbInfo['database_name'];
  $dbh = new PDO($dbConnString, $dbInfo['username'], $dbInfo['password'],array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''));
  $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

}
```

Comment: That's a PHP error, probably from a database statement, and showing us the ajax call doesn't really help much, as it has nothing to do with the error returned.

Comment: I'm not seeing the error you're describing. When I click on "book", the page posts back and appears to work ok.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a syntax error

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+Call+to+a+member+function+prepare%28%29+on+a+non-object

Comment: Look at the error and look at the code you posted. `Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object` - Where are you calling prepare()? On $dbh.. so what is $dbh? Well we know it's not an object and likely the source of your troubles.

Comment: @jameslafferty : the page is well displayed but if you check the response of the ajax call you'll see the error.

Comment: @MikeB About styntax error ? How can it work in French but not in English and Dutch while the code is the same ? Thank you for your help.

Comment: I probably jumped the gun on the syntax error bit.. but this has been covered to exhaustion http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+Call+to+a+member+function+prepare%28%29+on+a+non-object. I should have said "off topic because it's not going to help anyone else". Google has 240 thousand results for the same error. Your answer is simple, $dbh is not what you need it to be. Stop posting examples and links to your live site and focus on creating http://sscce.org instead of having people fix your logical mistakes for you. Why did you add that dbConnect function? It's not called anywhere...

Comment: By cherry-picking parts of your code **YOU THINK** have something to do with the problem are making it far far worse for everyone else here. Hence the sub-par, they can only repeat what the error is telling you, answers you're receiving.

Comment: @MikeB I'm quite new on this website, I take note of your remarks. Than you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The variable $dbh does not contain the database object